# Linear Algebra determinant equal 0

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

If $A ∈ M_n(R)$ is such that $A^2 = A$ and $A \neq I$ show that $\det(A) = 0$.

I know that in theory when $\det(A) = 0$, that $A \neq $ Identity matrix , but I am not sure how to show a proof for this question?

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: What does $A!$ mean?

Comment: A != I means $A \ne I$.

Comment: Rearrange and factor and you get $A(A-1)=0$. If $A$ were invertible, you could cancel and conclude $A=1.$ but since you are given that $A\neq 1$, you must conclude that $A$ is not invertible. Equivalently $\det A=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof by contradiction:

Suppose there exists an $A$ such that $detA \ne 0$ and $A\ne I$ and $A^2 = A.$

$detA \ne 0$ implies $A$ has an inverse.

$A^{-1}(A^2) = A^{-1}A\\
A = I$

But that contradicts our premise.

Answer (score 2):

If $A \neq I$ there exists a vector $v$ s.t. $Av \neq v$, so $w = Av - v \neq 0$. Then $Aw = A(Av - v) = A^{2}v - Av = Av - Av = 0$, so there exists a nonzero vector in the kernel of $A$. So we have $\text{det}(A) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Compute $A(A-I_n)=A^2-A=0.$ Thus $$\text{det}(A(A-I_n))=\text{det}(A)\text{det}(A-I_n)=0.$$ Use this to show that $\text{det}(A)=0.$ Hover over the following for the last bit of the argument.

> If $\text{det}(A)\text{det}(A-I_n)=0,$ then either $\det(A)=0$ or $\det(A-I_n)=0.$ If $\det(A)\ne 0,$ then $A$ is invertible, and therefore $A^2=A\implies A^{-1}A^2=A^{-1}A=I_n,$ contradicting our assumption, so conclude that $\det(A)=0.$

Comment: What if $\det(A-1)=0$?

Comment: @ziggurism, see your own comment.

Comment: Where did you get A(A−In)?

Comment: You can think of it as going backwards,  from $A-A=0.$ Then note that $A^2=A.$ playing with the properties is key to solving these types of problems.

Comment: thanks alot! Makes much more sense :)

Comment: No trouble. Please consider up-voting the answers you like, and click the check mark beneath the down vote for the one you find acceptable.

Comment: @shaziya Sorry, this shouldn't be the accepted answer. It is just a hint and there are more thorough solutions (such as the comment by ziggurism).