# $A^2 = A$ and prove $\det(A) = 0$ or $\det(A) = 1$

Tags: matrices, determinant

I am having some trouble finding a starting point for this problem.

> Suppose that $A^2 = A$. Prove that $\det(A) = 0$ or $\det(A) = 1$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you know about how determinants behave with matrix products?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear Algebra determinant equal 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435265/linear-algebra-determinant-equal-0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $$\det(A^2)=\det(A).$$
 Now, since $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B),$
we obtain $$\det(A)(\det(A)-1)=0$$ and we are done!

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $(\det A)^2=\det (A^2)= \det A$

Answer (score 1):

The proof is trivial if you can use the multiplication theorem for determinants: 
$$
\det(AB) = \det A\cdot\det B.
$$